# How to disable Chrome's Omnibox abroad detection?

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation

I frequently (a few times a day) connect via VPN with an abroad service and Google Chrome detects it as if I was abroad. And every time I do that it asks me:

[image]

How do I disable this thing?

Google provides [a little bit more explanation what it is](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1618699), but it doesn't seem to provide a way to disable it.

Comment: Does it happen when you use a custom query string?

Comment: @soandos What do you mean by a custom query string?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post can help you out: [Change Google's Search Domain in Google Chrome](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/08/change-googles-search-domain-in-google.html).

Instructions:

> 1. Close all Chrome windows.
> 2. Go to Chrome's user profile directory (for example, in Windows Vista and Windows 7 the path is: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User
>      Data).
> 3. Open the file Local State in a text editor like Notepad, TextEdit or gedit.
> 4. Find the two lines that include "last_known_google_url" and "last_prompted_google_url" and change the Google URL from
>      "http://www.google.tld/" (.tld=.co.uk, .fr, .co.jp etc.) to
>      "http://www.google.com/" or any other Google domain. 
>      [image]
> 5. Save the text file and restart Chrome.

Comment: They're both the same to me and set to the one I want, so this isn't a solution for me.